# Missing $ inserted in tabular equation environment

Tags: errors, texstudio

Been trying to this lines, but getting the error of Missing $ inserted ,

```
\begin{equation}
\left \{
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
R_{e_1,...,e_k} & when T_{e_1,...,e_k} > 0 & and BEL(R_{e_1,...,e_k}) \geq \alpha \\
& & \\
M+1& otherwise&\\
\end{tabular}
\right
\end{equation}
```

Could anyone please tell me why I'm getting This error?

Comment: Since you are using a table, anything inside is set as text mode and since you have math expressions, then these should be set in `$<math content>$`. `Hence, R_{e_1,...,e_k}` should be in math mode and not in text mode.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, I'd put this in a `cases` environment (additionally, BEL should be treated like an operator or function instead of the product of three variables B, E, and L; and also using `\ldots`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\bel}{BEL}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x = 
\begin{cases}
R_{e_1,\ldots,e_k} & \text{when } T_{e_1,\ldots,e_k} > 0 \text{ and } \bel(R_{e_1,\ldots,e_k}) \geq \alpha \\
M+1 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. However, I wouldn't put  a space between `\text{` and `when`.

Comment: No spaces mean the words get smashed up against the math. Would you add math-mode spacing, or do something else I've not considered?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: The only space I'd remove is the one immediately ahead of "when" -- observe that it is currently not lined up with the word "otherwise".

Answer (score 5):

All mathematical expressions, as `R_{e_1,...,e_k}` shoud be in dollars: `$R_{e_1,...,e_k}$` , or better `$R_{e_1,\ldots,e_k}$`.  But much easier and more natural is to change your tabular into `array` (using `amsmath` is assumed to have `\text` macro):

```
\begin{equation}
\left \{
\begin{array}{ccc}
R_{e_1,\ldots,e_k} & \text{when }T_{e_1,\ldots,e_k} > 0 & \text{ and }BEL(R_{e_1,\ldots,e_k}) \geq \alpha \\
& & \\
M+1& \text{otherwise}&\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

Please observe also that there was a missing dot after closing `\right` (should be `\right.`).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left \{
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
$R_{e_1,...,e_k}$ & when $T_{e_1,...,e_k} > 0$ & and $BEL(R_{e_1,...,e_k})\geq \alpha$\\
& & \\
$M+1$& otherwise&\\
\end{tabular}
\right \}
\end{equation}
```

[image: equa]

Comment: You didn't really tell him why he was getting the error...